# How to do SUM on array from outside file?

Tags: arrays, matrix, sum, fortran, fortran95

I'm newbie college student for programming studies,
so recently i have task to calculate matrix from outside files for Gauss Jordan Numeric Method, in the txt file i provide has 10 (x) and (y) data, and  declare with do functions to calculate the 10 data from the txt file each for  x^2, x^3, x^4, xy, x^2y

my question is : how to SUM (calculate total) each x^2, x^3 ... that was calculated by program ? i try do sum file in below and still got errors (the first argument of sum must not a scalar.)

the Fortran apps i use was Plato cc from Silverfrost.
I apologize if my english bad and my pogram looks funny.

i have 10 data in my txt looks like these :

```
(x)  (y)
12   10
5    6
28   8
9    11
20   17
6    24
32   9
2    7
1    30
26   22
```

in program below i open these files and want each x and y i provide read and calculate to get x^2, x^3, x^4, xy, x^2y

```
Program Gauss_Jordan
Real x(10),y(10),xj,yj,xj2,xj3,xj4,xjyj,xj2yj
 Open (10, file='Data.txt')
    Do j = 1,10
        Read(10,*) x(j), y(j)
        xj2 = x(j)**2
        xj3 = x(j)**3
        xj4 = x(j)**4
        xjyj = x(j)*y(j)
        xj2yj = (x(j)**2)*y(j)
            Do k = 1,10
            T(xj2) = SUM( xj2, dim=1)
            T(xj3) = SUM (xj3, dim=1)
            T(xj4) = SUM (xj4, dim=1)
            T(xjyj) = SUM (xjyj, dim=1)
            T(xj2yj) = SUM (xj2yj, dim=1)
            End Do
     End Do
 Close(10)
 End
```

for T(xj2) I want to get one result scalar result from SUM the all xj^2 that program has been calculated.

Like in excel was expected :

```
(A) is 1st xj^2 value that has been calculated
.
.
. 
until (J) is 10th xj^2 value that has been calculated
sxj^2 = SUM(Xj^2)
SUM (A-J)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'sum' intrinsic needs an array argument, which we can compute from the input arrays without using a loop, so your program could be:

```
Program Gauss_Jordan
    Real x(10), y(10), x2(10), x3(10), x4(10), xy(10), x2y(10)
    Open(10, file='Data.txt')
    Do j = 1, 10
        Read (10, *) x(j), y(j)
    End Do
    Close(10)
    x2 = x**2
    x3 = x**3
    x4 = x**4
    xy = x*y
    x2y = (x**2)*y
    sx2 = SUM(x2)
    sx3 = SUM(x3)
    sx4 = SUM(x4)
    sxy = SUM(xy)
    sx2y = SUM(x2y)
End
```

Comment: thanks for answering, oh right the specific declare for x2(10) to x2y(10) from start. once again thanks for answering and looks like this is what my lecture wanted the program to be, big appreciate ! :D

Answer (score 0):

From what I see I think you are misunderstanding what the SUM intrinsic does.  Since your example isn't storing xj2, xj3 etc. in arrays, SUM isn't going to be useful to you.  Instead you could declare totals as scalars (as you described you wanted) and simply add the individual xj2 variables in a loop as in the example below.

Also, you should get in the habit of using the implicit none declaration.  It will save you from unexpected errors due to spelling mistakes.

```
Program Gauss_Jordan

    implicit none
    Real x(10),y(10),xj,yj,xj2,xj3,xj4,xjyj,xj2yj
    real :: Txj2,Txj3,Txj4,Txjyj,Txj2yj
    integer :: j
    Txj2 = 0
    Txj3 = 0
    Txj4 = 0
    Txjyj= 0
    Txj2yj= 0

    Open (10, file='Data.txt')
    Do j = 1,10
        Read(10,*) x(j), y(j)
        xj2 = x(j)**2
        xj3 = x(j)**3
        xj4 = x(j)**4
        xjyj = x(j)*y(j)
        xj2yj = (x(j)**2)*y(j)
        Txj2   = Txj2   + xj2
        Txj3   = Txj3   + xj3
        Txj4   = Txj4   + xj4
        Txjyj  = Txjyj  + xjyj
        Txj2yj = Txj2yj + xj2yj
    End Do
    print *, 'Txj2 = ', Txj2
    Close(10)
 End
```

When I ran this I got the output below which is what I believe you intended:

```
3175
```

Comment: Surely part of the answer should be `txj2 = sum(x**2)` after the loop has run its course ?  I agree with your analysis that OP is not using `sum` correctly, but I think that it is applicable here.

Comment: thanks for answering, appreciate it,  i don't know if i'm misunderstood about sum intrinsic does, because my lecture gave me the lesson and example with sum and my lecture teach give me a basic formula of sum that was : SUM = SUM + X   and   RESULT  = SUM (l,(dim =a). and the example surely simple for sum a matrix that have been defined and declared (!) yet i know sum function really makes me confuse for these task but my lecture task me to use sum in "advanced" way for these XD anyway once again thanks and big appreciate :D